# How to keep the form fields filled in case of validation error Magento 2

Tags: php, magento, magento2

I have created a custom module for Distributor registration its having a custom form with some extra fields for registration. Distributor registration is working fine but i am not able to retain the form filed value in case there if there is server side validation error.

I have tried to followed customer registration module and form and found that Magento keeps the value in session like this.

in CreatePost.php controller

```
$this->session->setCustomerFormData($this->getRequest()->getPostValue());
```

and retaining the form value by bellow line of code in form.

```
<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($block->getFormData()->getCity()) ?>
```

Is there any other way i can use to keep the form filled in case of validation error ?

Comment: Did you get answer?

Answer (score 1):

In your controller file you need to set customer filed in this,

```
$this->getDataPersistor->set('city', $post);
```

Where `$this->getDataPersistor` is object of

```
\Magento\Framework\App\Request\DataPersistorInterface
```